# Build HTML page during maven build

Tags: maven

I am using Maven to build an HTML webapp. I have one profile for debug and another profile for release. In the debug profile I'd like to have un-compressed Javascript used in the HTML page but in the release profile I concatenate all of the Javascript files and then compress them using Googles Closure compiler.

So basically I have 2 lists of Javascript files that I need to write out as `<script>` tags into the HTML page based on which profile is selected.

Is there a Maven plugin that I could configure with different lists for different profiles that could generate the HTML file as necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much investigation I determined the best options was to write my own maven plugin. I have a simple .html template which contains directives on where to insert CSS and JS tags into the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Fifa Social - Hello World</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Hello World app for Fifa Social">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  $cssIncludes$
  $jsIncludes$

</head>
<body>
    <p>Page content</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I then have a Maven plugin that runs in the "generate-sources" phase of the Maven lifecycle which takes the template and replaces the `$cssIncludes$` and `$jsIncludes$` with the appropriate list of `<script>` and `<link>` tags. (Note: I am using the [antlr stringtemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) Java library as a dependency for my plugin).

I can't post the actual plugin since it is a proprietary project but it is a single Java class that extends from AbstractMojo

- it has `@parameter` properties to read the `<configuratioon>` from the POM

  - location of html template
  - location of output file
  - the list of JS files
  - the list of CSS files
- during execute it

  - reads the html template from a file and stores is as a string
  - creates an `org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate` from the html template
  - using the default `org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.DefaultTemplateLexer`.
  - loops through the JS and CS files from the configuration creating the `<script>` and `<link>` tags as strings
  - uses `template.setAttribute` to bind the built string to $cssIncludes$ and $jsIncludes$
  - writes the template to the files system

It works quite nicely. I simply send a different list of JS and CSS files to the plugin based on the current Maven profile.

Answer (score 2):

If maven resources plugin (with [filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) from [properties files](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-filter-resources-based-on-values-from-a-properties-file.html)) is not enough maybe you could use one of freemaker or [velocity maven plugins](http://code.google.com/p/velocity-maven-plugin/wiki/HowToUseThePlugin) to generate your pages.

I've used velocity plugin to generate one HTML page to test my JS code with maven jasmine plugin, and another HTML page for production. The code will be released soon. If you need it please ping so I'll remember to add the link.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a short search via [Google i found a Maven Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/Maven) which can be used to do compression. So based on that it's no problem to have different profiles, as you already mentioned, to compress or not to compress or just leave the files without compression.

Comment: It isn't the compression that is the problem - it is creating the correct `<script>` tag in the HTML file. In the debug case I have several js files (script1.js, script2.js, script3.js) that need to have individual `<script>` tags. In the release case I concatenate all of the files into `site-scripts.js` which is a compressed version of all of them and so I only need one `<script>` tag. I ended up writing a Maven plugin to do it for me.